# Write random date to a file Python

Tags: python, fwrite

Python 2.7.13 - version

I have a .py that contains a few methods that generates random info(Date,Name,Phone number).

```
def strTimeProp(start, end, format, prop):
    stime = time.mktime(time.strptime(start, format))
    etime = time.mktime(time.strptime(end, format))
    ptime = stime + prop * (etime - stime)
    return time.strftime(format, time.localtime(ptime))

def randomDate(start, end, prop):
    return strTimeProp(start, end, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p', prop)

print randomDate("1/1/2008 12:00 AM", "1/1/2009 12:00 AM", random.random())

f = open("CDR.txt" ,"w")
f.write(randomDate)
f.close()
```

I'm getting a typeError with `f.write(randomDate)` it's expecting a string or buffer and not a function. How can I send the output of the print statement to the .txt file I'm writing to?

Comment: capture the output of your function first. `rd = randomDate(..); print(rd), ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the function `randomDate` to `f.write` without any parameters

This will resolve your issue:

```
f.write(randomDate("1/1/2008 12:00 AM", "1/1/2009 12:00 AM", random.random()))
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! Is there a more concise way of accomplishing this?

Comment: @DJ2 There are a couple ways to make it more concise that I can think of. You can specify default parameters in your function so you can call it without arguments. Or, you could store its value in a variable and pass that to `f.write`. There are probably more ways, but your question is a little unclear.